# Add gradient overlay under a photo label using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to convert a bunch of photos using imagemagick. However, I hadn't figured out how to **overlay** an  image with gradient and write some text on it. I know the text part though:

```
convert IMG_8408.jpg \
    -font URWChanceryMediumI \
    -pointsize 250 \
    -draw "gravity south
        fill black text 0,40 'Some text stuff here'" \
    test.jpg
```

Is there a way to add a white gradient to the bottom? Note, that the image size may vary.

---

What I have:

[image]

---

What I want:

[image]

---

I picked the colors so that it's clearly visible what I want to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve desired output with 3 commands:

a. create the upper part of your image (a solid rectangle with your selected background color):

```
convert -size 640x200 xc:#A02B2B background.jpg
```

b. create another image containing the text over a gradient:

```
convert -size 640x110 gradient:#A02B2B-#126B27 -pointsize 25 -draw "gravity south fill black text 0,40 'Some text stuff here'" text.jpg
```

c. combine the images to obtain the final output:

```
montage background.jpg text.jpg -tile 1x2 -geometry +0+0 output.jpg
```

*Note: I modified text creation parameters in step 2 to keep the command short, but you can add back your original settings*

Answer (score 0):

*Use the following command:*

```
magick -size 640x310 -define gradient:vector="0,107 0,0" gradient:"#a02b2b-#126b27" -flip -gravity south -font script-mt-bold -pointsize 48 -annotate +0+24 "Some text stuff here" output.png
```

[image]