# Rounded rectangle with shadow and gradient filling

Tags: imagemagick

Using Magick I managed to create a simple rounded rectangle filled with a solid color and having a shadow:

```
magick montage -background none -size 300x200 xc:none -fill green -draw "roundRectangle 0,0 300,200 8,8" -shadow  -geometry +10+10
```

The result is the following:

[image]

Is there an easy way to slighty modify the command in order to have a gradient fill (for instance from green to red) instead of the solid green, mantaining all other aspects (rounded corners and shadow) ?

The ideal result is the following:

[image]

Comment: Make a mask of the green and use it as a write mask for overwriting the image using `-size 200x300 gradient:green-red -rotate -90`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72951498/18686041 may help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do that.

```
magick start.png \
  \( +clone -size "%Hx%W" +delete gradient:green-red -rotate -90 -write MPR:gradient +delete \) \
  \( +clone -alpha off -fill black +opaque green -fill white -opaque green -write MPR:alpha +delete \) \
  \( MPR:gradient MPR:alpha -compose copyalpha -composite \) \
  +compose -composite result.png
```

[image]

It works like this:

**line 1:** Load original image

**line 2:** Clone original image (just to get its size) then set the size for the forthcoming `-gradient` the same but rotated 90 degrees so it runs left-right instead of top-bottom. Make the gradient you want, rotate to correct orientation, and save in **MPR** *"Magick Persistent Register"* called `gradient` for later. Delete it for now.

**line 3:** Clone the original image. Make all non-green pixels black and all green pixels white. Save in another **MPR** called `alpha`. Delete it for now.

**line 4:** Reload gradient and alpha from MPRs and force the alpha channel into the gradient. The gradient will now be transparent wherever the original image was not green.

**line 5:** Reset back to default compose method and composite the new layer (containing gradient transparent where original was not green) over the original image and save.